# all input field validation through single/minimum line on code with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form in which I have 30 input boxes and 10 text areas and 3 select boxes (**updated**)  field and all are mandatory fields.

How do I apply validation through jQuery /javascript together for all input fields that it `can't be blank/empty/NULL.`

I don't want to use each time each input box's ID and create a separate validation for each input box and text area.

If any input field is blank then it's border become red and when a use going to write something then become normal( no border i.e. remove that class)

**UPDATE**:

There are also select boxes ..how do I validate them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the red border from each text, 
   textarea, and list box field.
2. Filter out
   elements that contain at least 1
   non-whitespace character - \S+
3. Add a red
   border to the remaining elements

javascript

```
function validate() {
  return $("input:text,textarea,select").removeClass('blank').filter(function() {
    return !/\S+/.test($(this).val());
  }).addClass('blank').size() == 0;
}

$('#form').submit(validate);
```

css

```
.blank {
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

Comment: it validate but page go on action page , it does not stop at that page and that error css e disply only for few seconds

Comment: and in css there should be `border`  instead of  `blank`

Comment: it was submitting the form because i just posted a snippet. the `onsubmit` handler function must return false or stop the event to prevent the form from submitting. thanks for pointing out the css fix.

Comment: now it works fine, but it does not work on select box. and one more things i want when user going to write something then css should be remove.

Comment: i fixed that using second set of code of first answer given by Karim.
but select box still unvalidated?

Comment: i had problems with select boxes too. apparently the browser (or jquery) is automatically selecting the first item. So I tried putting a junk item as the first option whose value was blank as it fits nicely with our textfields and textareas . `<option value="">Please Select...</option>`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {

    // if there are some empty inputs
    if($(":input[value]").length != $(":input").length)) {

        // filter out the empty ones, apply some CSS
        $(":input").filter(function() {
            return this.value.length == 0;
        }).addClass("blank");

        // do not submit
        return false;
    }
});

$(":input").blur(function() {
    if(this.value.length > 0) {
        $(this).removeClass("blank");
    }
});
```

Comment: working fine but there is two syntax error
   1. remove extra `)` after .length function
   2.add `(` after `solid;` this shoud be
 css("border","1px red solid";`)`