# Validation and submitting only if it returns true

Tags: jquery

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my form validation to work.

As of right now, it will submit if there are empty fields.

I'm trying to get it so that it won't submit if there are empty fields.

The catch is that there are a dynamic number of input fields. The user can create new ones (up to twenty).

They all follow the rule of where they are named 'NAME'+i (so the first field is NAME1, second is NAME2, etc.)

I've looked into things like [this](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jquery/form_validation/index.html), but I just can't get them to work.

I'm using jQuery.

Comment: What about showing us your code? **Waste of our time**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this link it might help you

[all input field validation through single/minimum line on code with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391456/all-input-field-validation-through-jquery-in-single-line)

and also you cans use the below to check for blank fields...

```
$("#myForm input[type=text]").val() != ""
```

hope this helps....